# How to fix "Expected to return a value in arrow function" with reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, eslint, arrow-functions

I have two function in my react-app components

```
componentDidMount() {
        if(Object.keys(this.props.praticiens).length>0)
            Object.keys(this.props.praticiens).map((praticien) => {
                if(this.props.praticiens[praticien].identifiant_user === getUrlParams(window.location.hash).identifiant_user)
                    this.setState({
                        praticien:this.props.praticiens[praticien].id_user
                    })
            })
    }

    handleChangePraticien = (praticien) => {
        this.setState({ praticien }, () => {
            Object.keys(this.props.praticiens).map((praticien) => {
                if(this.state.praticien === this.props.praticiens[praticien].id_user)
                    this.props.selectPraticienFunction(this.props.praticiens[praticien].identifiant_user);
            })
        })
    }
```

When I run it, I get:

```
Line 26:64:  Expected to return a value in arrow function  array-callback-return
  Line 36:64:  Expected to return a value in arrow function  array-callback-return
```

Such as the Line 26 is beginning `Object.keys(this.props.praticiens).map((praticien) => {` on componentDidMount and Line 36 is the same line on the handleChangePraticien function

How can I fix it ?

Comment: Your if statements need brackets `{}`. You can only remove them if the line inside the if statement is a single line.

Comment: @theblackgigant - Single *statement*, not single line. They're all single statements. (That said, I much prefer always using `{}` on control-flow statmenets.)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

> Line 26:64:  Expected to return a value in arrow function  array-callback-return

Since you do not care about returning a value from the arrow function and you are not using the array returned by the `map()`, you should be using `forEach()` function instead.

```
componentDidMount() {
        if(Object.keys(this.props.praticiens).length>0)
            Object.keys(this.props.praticiens).forEach((praticien) => {
                if(this.props.praticiens[praticien].identifiant_user === getUrlParams(window.location.hash).identifiant_user)
                    this.setState({
                        praticien:this.props.praticiens[praticien].id_user
                    })
            })
    }

    handleChangePraticien = (praticien) => {
        this.setState({ praticien }, () => {
            Object.keys(this.props.praticiens).forEach((praticien) => {
                if(this.state.praticien === this.props.praticiens[praticien].id_user)
                    this.props.selectPraticienFunction(this.props.praticiens[praticien].identifiant_user);
            })
        })
```

Answer (score 80):

Changing {} to () worked for me

from `map(() => {})` to `map(() => ())`

Comment: It worked for me. Can you explain the difference?

Comment: Fail to see why on Earth it's the highest-voted answer. Not only it's a "magic dust" one, but also it never mentions the fact that "fixing" the code this way doesn't actually prevent the return value spoilage, as `map` return value itself is never used.

Answer (score 16):

The Array.prototype.forEach() and Array.prototype.map() are used for two differents purposes.

- **Array.prototype.forEach()**

The Array.prototype.forEach is used to simply loop over an array's items but doesn't return any special value. Its signature is :

`forEach(callback, [thisArg]) => undefined`

Only the first argument `callback` is mandatory and its signature is `(current [, index, array]) => void` where the only required argument is `current`

*Example*

```
[1,2,3].forEach( item => console.log(item))
// Output 1 2 3 undefined
```

- **Array.prototype.map()**

This function is mostly used to create a new `Array` from an other one. Unlike the `forEach` function, it returns an `Array`. Its signature is the following:

`map(callback [, thisArg]) => Array`.
Just like `forEach`, only the first argument is mandatory but the callback signture is different: `(current [, index, array]) => any`.
The final array will contain every value returned by the callback after each iteration.

*Example*

```
[1,2,3].map(item => item ** 2)
// Output [1 4 9]
```

More informations over there:

[Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/forEach)

[Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/map)

Answer (score 9):

You're using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) as though it were [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). Don't use `map` unless you're going to use the array it creates from the return values of the callback. Use `forEach`, `for-of`, or any of the many other ways to loop through arrays described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476).

Answer (score 1):

If you need to return an array, but also place conditionals in the loop so that some items may not be returned you can combine `.forEach` with `.push` like this:

```
class Profiles extends Component {
  profilesArray() {
    let profiles_array = [];

    this.props.profiles.forEach((profile) => {
      // some condition
      if (profile.id !== this.props.whatever) {
        profiles_array.push(
          <ContentCard key={profile.profile_id}>
            <p>My Content</p>
          </ContentCard>
        );
      }
    });

    return profiles_array;
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <h1>Profiles</h1>
        {this.profilesArray()}
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return something for each iteration when you iterate a map, so I suggest making these alterations:

```
list.map(() => {
   return (
    // block of code to be executed
   )
})
```

or simply

```
list.map(() => (
    // block of code to be executed
))
```

Answer (score 0):

this is just one of Errors: Array.prototype.map() expects a return value from arrow function.eslintarray-callback-return

```
{cableCars.map((cableCar: typeCblCar) => {
  <CableCar key={cableCar.id} cableCar={cableCar} dispatch={dispatch} />
})}
```

Does not work, but this implicite return works perfect:

```
{cableCars.map((cableCar: typeCblCar) => (
  <CableCar key={cableCar.id} cableCar={cableCar} dispatch={dispatch} />
))}
```

This was my problem with useReducer in TypeScript.
The answer gived by heremyas solve my agony
So from my over-complicated workaround this is pure beauty.
Thanks heremyas and long live stackoverflow!

Answer (score 0):

Just change {} with ()

In a React application, the "map" is often used to render components as the return value. Like in this example using parentheses for indicating a direct return call.

```js
previewPosts?.map((post, i) => (
    <PostCard key={post.id} {...{post, num: i }} />
))
```

or like this using brackets with an explicit return call.

```js
previewPosts?.map((post, i) => {
    return (
        <PostCard key={post.id} {...{post, num: i }} />
    )
})
```

If you are not returning anything using either of these techniques, then the "Expected a return value in arrow function" error will be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Imho, no answer provides the explanation of why you use () instead of {}. So, here you go:

The difference between () and {} is that () is the shorthand for a return statement, whereas {} represents just the function. So, by writing **list.map(() => ())**, you are essentially using the short version of:

```
list.map(() => (
   return (
    // return stuff
   )
));
```

whereas using {} is just writting the block of the function without any return value:

```
list.map(() => {
    // execute stuff
});
```

Hope I could shed some light for some fellow programmers. Happy coding ✌️

Answer (score -1):

```js
return this.props.selectPraticienFunction(this.props.praticiens[praticien].identifiant_user)
```